# Insulating an outside water purification system against heat in Arizona

Tags: insulation, water-tank, water-purification

I have a tall stainless steel water purification system tank that is located outside of my home in Tucson,AZ. I used pipe insulation tubes on the copper piping. I plan to also put up a solar UV blocking cloth and a small roof over it. Will a water heater blanket help to insulate the steel tank FROM the intense heat here? Any other ideas on how to protect it? How to protect the large catchment tanks from the heat?

Comment: Don't forget that a shiny silver tank will reflect a lot of that light and, therefore, heat.

Comment: Obviously insulation reduces heat transfer. I'm not clear on your actual question.

Comment: @FreeMan, raw metal gets hot in the sun, which means that it absorbs more than it reflects. I'm not sure I take your point.

Comment: @isherwood: I presume you meant to say it absorbs more than it radiates (+ conducts + convects).  Reflected energy doesn't affect the heat balance, because it's both incident and outgoing.

Comment: I meant reflect because that's what the comment above mine said. :)

Answer (score 0):

The blanket is part of the solution.   However You are going to get a lot of heat from the sun's rays.

The best solution would be to build an enclosure around the tank to keep it in the shade all day.  If the sun can't get to it it can't heat it.  You will only lose heat transfer through the air.  There is where the blanket helps.